# Using 'argparse.ArgumentError' in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to use the `ArgumentError` exception in the `argparse` module in Python, but I can't figure out how to use it. The signature says that it should be called as `ArgumentError(argument, message)`, but I can't figure out what `argument` should be. I think it should be some part of the parser object, but I couldn't find any documentation for it.

Comment: Related: [Is it bad form to raise `ArgumentError` by hand?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8293325/1497596)

Comment: You can use it within a custom `Action` class, just as the existing classes do.  But I can't imagine a reason to do so outside of the `parser`.   It doesn't anything special - just adds the `Action` name to the error message.  Study its use in the code.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

From [the source documentation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Lib/argparse.py#l34):

> ArgumentError: The exception raised by ArgumentParser objects when there are errors with the parser's actions. Errors raised while parsing the command-line are caught by ArgumentParser and emitted as command-line messages.

The `argument` parameter of the constructor is the `Action` object from which the exception is raised. Usually there is no need to raise it outside of an `Action` subclass, and when subclassing it, there is no need to raise it explicitly; you usually raise `ValueError` (or whatever is appropriate) instead.

#### Float values between 0 and 1

In regards to your comment, that you only want to accept floating point values between 0 and 1. For this you should use the ability to define custom types. You can do it for example like this:

```
def percentFloat (string):
    value = float(string)
    if value < 0 or value > 1:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('Value has to be between 0 and 1')
    return value

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('test', type=percentFloat)
parser.parse_args()
```

Note that this is also safe against non-floats as `float(string)` will raise a `ValueError` for non-floats which also triggers an invalid type error by the `argparse` module. [`ArgumentTypeError`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.2/Lib/argparse.py#l725) is just a way to specify a custom error message.

#### Mutually exclusive parameters

For mutually exclusive parameters, you should use [`argparse.add_mutually_exclusive_group`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).

#### Parameter dependency

Parameter dependency isn’t really something that should be done by the argument *parser*. For semantic details, you should instead simply do it yourself:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.w and not args.p:
    parser.error('-p is required when -w is set.')
```

You can use [`ArgumentParser.error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.error) to raise custom error message which will interrupt the program and print to the console.

But of course in such a basic situation it would make a lot more sense just to implicitly guess `-p` if possible.

Comment: That isn't right.  If I just send the value, I get `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'option_strings'`.

Comment: And by the way, I want to use it because I want to do type checking that the module doesn't directly support. For example, I want a floating point value that is between 0 and 1.  argparse lets you specify that it should be a float, but I have to manually check the range.  This seems like the correct error to emit when the value is wrong.

Comment: @asmeurer Edited my answer to give you an example on how to do that.

Comment: The downvote is because the answer is wrong.  ArgumentError(1.1, "Value out of range") raises AttributeError, as I mentioned above.  This needs to be some kind of internal argparse object, but I can't figure out what. And by the way, another example of when you might want to do this is when you want to define a non-trivial dependency on the arguments, which as far as I can tell, the argparse module does not directly support.  Something like the `-w` option requires the `-p` option, or `-n` and `-N` are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 33):

While `parser.error()` is what most people probably want, it is also possible to use argparse.ArgumentError() (as the question asks.)  You need a reference to the argument, like the `bar_arg` in the example below:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
bar_arg = parser.add_argument('--bar')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.bar == 'xyzzy':
    raise argparse.ArgumentError(bar_arg, "Can't be 'xyzzy'")

if args.foo == 'xyzzy':
    parser.error("Can't be 'xyzzy'")
```

This will result in output like the one below:

```
$ python argparse_test.py --foo xyzzy
usage: argparse_test.py [-h] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR]
argparse_test.py: error: Can't be 'xyzzy'

$ python argparse_test.py --bar xyzzy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "argparse_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise argparse.ArgumentError(bar_arg, "Can't be 'xyzzy'")
argparse.ArgumentError: argument --bar: Can't be 'xyzzy'
```

Comment: This is a good example of how using `ArgumentError` outside of the `parser` is possible, but probably inferior to using `parser.error`.

Comment: @hpaulj, yes, but ArgumentError has one benefit: it lets you know which switch was the offending one.

Comment: Well, if you write your error message well, then you'd be sure to _mention_ which switch was the offending one. Creating a separate variable for each added argument can be very cumbersome...

Comment: @Praveen It's a question of preference I suppose.  Myself I prefer the variable to writing "'--foo' can't be 'xyzzy'", since I then have to remember what the proper name of the switch was (it's not necessarily the same as the attribute to `args`).  But honestly, I think `parser.error()` should include the name of the offending switch by default.

Comment: You can use `args.bar` as the argument to `ArgumentError`, not only `bar_arg`.