# Is it bad form to raise ArgumentError by hand?

Tags: python, exception, argparse

If you want to add an extra check not provided by `argparse`, such as:

```
if variable a == b then c should be not None
```

...is it permissible to raise `ArgumentError` yourself?

Or, should you raise `Exception` instead?

Also what is common practice for this kind of situation? Say that you add a piece of code that's almost like a local extension of the library. Should you use the same exception type(s) as those provided by the library you are extending?

Comment: For my own reference: the Python builtin is ValueError, not ArgumentError

Comment: Related: [How to use `argparse.ArgumentError` in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8107713/1497596)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with raising an ArgumentError. You can use it anytime the arguments you receive are not what you expected them to be, including checking range of numbers.

Also, yes, in general it's alright for you to use the same exceptions provided by a given library if you are writing an extension to that library.

Regarding raising `Exception`s, I wouldn't do that. You should always raise a specific exception so you know how to handle it in the code. Catching `Exception` objects should be done at the highest level in your application, to catch and log all exceptions that you missed.